# Change commission_status paid when withdraw_status vendor is completed

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, wpdb

I need to change commission_status paid automatically after changing commission_status paid when the withdraw_status vendor equals "completed,"
not check mark.

action:`$actions = '<a class="wcfm_order_mark_delivered wcfm-action-icon" href="#" data-affiliate_id="' . $wcfm_affiliate_order_single->ID . '"><span class="wcfmfa fa-check-circle text_tip" data-tip="' . esc_attr__( 'Mark Paid', 'wc-frontend-manager-affiliate' ) . '"></span></a>';`

JS:

```
function markWCFMPaid(item) {
        jQuery('#wcfm_affiliate_stats_listing_expander').block({
            message: null,
            overlayCSS: {
                background: '#fff',
                opacity: 0.6
            }
        });
        var data = {
            action        : 'mark_wcfm_affiliate_order_paid',
            affiliate_id  : item.data('affiliate_id')
        }   
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:       'POST',
            url: wcfm_params.ajax_url,
            data: data,
            success:    function(response) {
                if($wcfm_affiliate_stats_table) $wcfm_affiliate_stats_table.ajax.reload();
                jQuery('#wcfm_affiliate_stats_listing_expander').unblock();
            }
        });
    }
```

**function**

```
/**
 * Mark Affiliate Order Paid
 */
function wcfmaf_mark_affiliate_order_paid() {
    global $WCFM, $WCFMaf, $wpdb;

    $affiliate_id = absint( $_POST['affiliate_id'] );

    if( $affiliate_id ) {
        $sql  = "SELECT * FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}wcfm_affiliate_orders`";
        $sql .= " WHERE 1=1";
        $sql .= " AND ID = {$affiliate_id}";
        $affiliate_details = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );

        if( !empty( $affiliate_details ) ) {
            foreach( $affiliate_details as $affiliate_detail ) {

                // Update Affiliate Order Status Update
                $wpdb->update("{$wpdb->prefix}wcfm_affiliate_orders", array('commission_status' => 'paid', 'commission_paid_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ))), array('ID' => $affiliate_id), array('%s', '%s'), array('%d'));

                //$wcfm_affiliate_user = get_userdata( $affiliate_detail->affiliate );


            }
        }
    }

    die;
}
```